# How can I enable test payment mode of stripe payment gateway on WordPres

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I want to test the stripe payment gateway on my WordPress website. I have enabled the test mode from my stripe account:

[image]

But on the WordPress I can see the payment is disabled:
[image]

Can you tell me how can I enable it?

Comment: message in your screenshot is pretty clear: your stripe account is missing business information, and you need to update it in order to get Payments/payouts enabled.

Comment: OH! let me try it

Comment: Updated but still showing that message (Disabled).

Comment: please take a look at this support topic for further information: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/payouts-disabled/

Comment: If the above support article doesn't resolve the issue it looks like you'd want to talk to Stripe support about getting your account fully enabled.  https://support.stripe.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a discussion better suited for Stripe's support team